# DynamicNodeCollection e-shop C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing shop andi have question, because i dont know how can i do it correctly.
When i click on random category, always i get this same category (first category). Look at my code please. Thank you so much:

```
public class ProductListDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();
        foreach (Category c in db.Category)
        {
            DynamicNode n = new DynamicNode();
            n.Title = c.CategoryTitle;
            n.Key = "Kategoria_" + c.CategoryID;
            returnValue.Add(n);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

It is my product's node provider.

Comment: I could do with a bit more to go on, how do you mean when you click a random category? Could you provide the code for that please?

So your method is basically looping through your db collection, what's in db.Category? have you got multiple objects there or just 1?

Comment: Category is a Model. There is CategoryID, CategoryTitle, CategoryDescription and CategoryFile. In db i have 3 categories to tests. On homepage i have categories, and when i click one it is going to other view (ProductCategory), inside i have @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath(), and it give me always CategoryTitle where id = 1. When i click on second category, or 3 category it always is START > NAME OF CATEGORY where id = 1. I need repair it.

Comment: i need here RouteValues()? My routeConfig is default.